# Retrofit IlegalStateExecption: closed and open request

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

Shite title because it's 2 errors both are IlegalState:

So error 1 is

```
Process: dk.swibbid.mz, PID: 11764
java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot make a new request because the previous response is still open: please call response.close()
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.enterNetworkInterceptorExchange(RealCall.kt:229)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:66)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at dk.swibbid.mz.api.RetrofitClient$requestInfoInterceptor$1.intercept(RetrofitClient.kt:50)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at dk.swibbid.mz.api.RetrofitClient$authInterceptor$1.intercept(RetrofitClient.kt:38)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.kt:221)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

So i tried to close all my interseptors responses by like this:

```
class RetrofitClient {

private val BASE_URL = "xxxx"
private val USER_AGENT = "Android App"

private val gson = GsonBuilder()
    .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    .create()

private val tokenStorage: PreferenceTokenStorage
val client: Retrofit

init {
    tokenStorage = PreferenceTokenStorage()

    val httpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    httpLoggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
    val authInterceptor = label@ Interceptor { chain: Interceptor.Chain ->
        val originalRequest = chain.request()
        if (tokenStorage.hasToken()) {
            val request = originalRequest
                .newBuilder()
                .addHeader(AUTHORIZATION, tokenStorage.accessToken!!)
                .build()
            chain.proceed(request).also {
                it.close()
            }
        }
        chain.proceed(originalRequest).also {
            it.close()
        }


    }

    val requestInfoInterceptor = Interceptor { chain: Interceptor.Chain ->
        val originalRequest = chain.request()
        val requestWithUserAgent = originalRequest.newBuilder()
            .header("User-Agent", USER_AGENT)
            .header("App-Version", BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME)
            .build()

        chain.proceed(requestWithUserAgent).also {
            it.close()
        }
    }

    val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
        .addInterceptor(authInterceptor)
        .addInterceptor(requestInfoInterceptor)
        .authenticator(
            TokenAuthenticator(tokenStorage)
        )

    client = Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .client(httpClient.build())
        .build()

}
}
```

But doing this gives me this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.request(RealBufferedSource.kt:203)
    at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.kt:247)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I couldn't find any answers anywhere and i've also tried to just close only one interceptor at a time but that don't work either. I have being sitting for hours trying to find an answer. I need some help here.

this is the two functions im calling from my view model:

```
 fun registerUser(userData: UserData){
    if (networkCheck()) return
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
        userDataRepository.insertUserData(userData).enqueue(object : Callback<BaseResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<BaseResponse>,
                response: Response<BaseResponse>
            ) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    response.body()
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        getApplication(),
                        "Error: " + (response.body()?.errorResponse
                            ?: getApplication<SwibbidApplication>().getString(
                                R.string.error_unknown
                            )),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<BaseResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(
                    getApplication(),
                    "Error: " + getApplication<SwibbidApplication>().getString(R.string.error_network_failed),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }

        })
    }
}

fun registerWithProfilePicture(part: MultipartBody.Part,userData: UserData){
    if (networkCheck()) return
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
        userDataRepository.uploadProfilePicture(part).enqueue(object :
            Callback<LinkResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<LinkResponse>,
                response: Response<LinkResponse>
            ) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        userData.photoUrl = response.body()?.links?.get(0)
                        registerUser(userData)
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        getApplication(),
                        "Error: " + (response.body()?.error
                            ?: getApplication<SwibbidApplication>().getString(
                                R.string.error_unknown
                            )),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<LinkResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Error: " + getApplication<SwibbidApplication>().getString(R.string.error_network_failed), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's related to a memory leak introduced in version 3.14.1 and new versions fixed this issue. What version of OkHttp are you using?

Comment: I was using the newest version, but i switched to the old 3.14 because i can't find out how to fix this

Comment: That's wierd, so it might be a bug, you can creating an issue in OkHttp GitHub repo, I am sure folks there will help you.